# Hide frame from other frameset

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, frame

I am trying **to hide** (or edit inline attribute) **a frame** from an **other framset** by clicking a button.

I used : `$(".HiddenFrame").hide();`

But seems that I can not find the item.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/exqLgrym/1/)

Comment: Like this [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/exqLgrym/2/)  ?  or this [Second Link](http://jsfiddle.net/gRTah/)

Comment: frames are separate windows, you need to traverse to parent window and work from there. The windows are all insulated from each other

Answer (score 0):

"As far as my understanding of things goes, you need to perform actions like hide on divs. Basically, whatever you are trying to affect needs to respond to the css display attribute. If you must use frames, I would strongly suggest you use divs instead, then you will need to write some jQuery that actually removes the frame from the DOM instead of just trying to hide it."

**Source** :[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791700/jquery-how-to-hide-a-frame-on-parent)

and see this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24030228/completely-hide-frame-in-framesets-using-javascript-or-jquery)